# How to implement OnDrawAll method in pdfviewer by barteksc / AndroidPdfViewer

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, edit, pdf-viewer

How to implement OnDrawAll and how to enable/disable ondraw method for  pdfviewer by barteksc / AndroidPdfViewer or any other pdfviwer